# How to install foundation kits, bypass the error "You don't appear to be in a ZURB stack project, so we can't automatically instal l building blocks"

Tags: ruby, node.js, zurb-foundation

I Install the last foundation client and liked to install a kit in my projects. I use Linux Fedora 25, Windows 7, 8 and 10. I always got the same error.

How can install foundation kits or blocks using the command line?

I did:

```
Foundation new
<and give the new projectname name>

cd <projectname>
npm start
foundation kits install dashboard
You don't appear to be in a ZURB stack project, so we can't automatically instal
l building blocks
? Do you want to download as a zip file? No
```

> foundation blocks install app-dashboard-layout

give the same output.

Why foundation don't detect the stack project? I have ruby, gem, node, npm, glup, bower, mongo, yo installed.

program versions:
Foundation Cli 2.2.2
Bower 1.8.0
node 6.10.3
npm 3.10.0
mocha 3.4.1

I know that i can unzip the file but i don't understand why foundation don't detect his own fresh created projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foundation new
```

Prompts come up, the third option needs to be ZURB

```
> Foundation for sites
> <project name>
> ZURB template
```

then

```
cd <project> 
foundation kits install <kit>
```

I believe you have to select ZURB template. I just tried with the following commands, it seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine if i select Zurb template